# Switch pattern matching case fallback

Tags: c#, switch-statement, pattern-matching

Consider following code:

```
void Foo(object value)
{
    switch (value)
    {
        case Int16 i16:
        case Int32 i32:
            // Do something with i32
            break;
    }
}
```

Can you explain why is i32 unassigned? I get it that i16 is definitely not assigned since it was in the previous scope but I dont get it in case of i32.

Comment: I guess the problem is that the compiler cannot tell which variable (`i16` or `i32`) is the one that gets assigned so has to assume both are unassigned.

Comment: @DavidG Yes, you are right. I forget that it can happen that the value is actually Int16, so `i16` is assigned and `i32` is then unassigned. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a comment on [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/#div-comment-120495) by Mads Torgersen (C# langauge PM at Microsoft):

> If you have switch fall through, variables introduced by either label will not be definitely assigned so they won't be useful in the body. Consider this code:
>
> ```
> case string s:
> case null:
>     WriteLine(s); // Can't! s may not have been assigned.
> ```

So the compiler cannot tell which variable was assigned and has to assume both are not.